# Python tkinter widget image animation function with after in a loop misbehaving

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, animation, tkinter

I am slowly learning my way through Python and tkinter. :)

In a game I'm making there are animations of images displayed within widgets (namely buttons).

Animating frame-by-frame is mundane, so I came up with a function to help me automate a 10-frame animation.

In a loop of `range(10)` (as I have 10 frames) the function calls the `after()` method which has a function callback, each displaying next frame of animation.

Since time within the after method is larger for each consecutive iteration of the loop, each new frame should be displayed nicely after given time (here it's 34ms).

That's all fine in theory, however when I run the code and appropriate functions are called, the button does not animate properly. Only the last frame seems to pop out.

The way I see it, after some reading on how tkinter works, is that each after in a loop should set independent callback in tkinter's "timeline" to be called after some time. Thus in my opinion this code should work.

What do you make of it? What've I got wrong, is my logic about `after()` in a loop off?

```
#Python 3.4.3
def animateMine(object):
    global firstAnimateMineCall
    for frame in range(10):
        frame += 1
        time = 34 * frame
        root.after(time, lambda: mineAnimationFrame(object, frame))
    if firstAnimateMineCall and frame == 10:
        root. after(500 , lambda: animateAllMines(object))
    firstAnimateMineCall = False
```

In the doubtful event this'd be useful:

```
def mineAnimationFrame(object, frame):
    tempDir = "Resources/Mine/saperx_mine_%s.png" % (frame)
    tempImage = PhotoImage(file=tempDir)
    object.configure(image=tempImage)
    object.image = tempImage
    object.disabled = True
```

Comment: This problem has been answered many times. "tempImage" is only in the function scope, so is garbage collected when the function "mineAnimationFrame" returns so there is no image left to display.  See the green background text at effbot http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm  (and a searce on this site for something like tkinter image reference should yield many of the similar posts)

Comment: @curly-joe You've clearly not taken your time to read through the code I provided. I've read through the effbot a while ago, great site! My code adjusts for this by `object.image = tempImage` so the image is not garbage. Also, if you've read through it you'd notice that I explicitly stated that the last frame is visible, which would not be the case, if the func image garbage return would be the problem... :)

Comment: @CurlyJoe I'm responding again because I think the message reply didn't get through to you and I still need help with this issue :)

Comment: You overlay "object.image" each time so it only contains the latest image=the previous image is garbage collected.  The comment was a hint that you should see/print what object.image contains after the function returns.  Good programming IMHO would be to read each image into a list_of_images and then pass a number to the function to display list_of_images[x].  And note that lists are mutable so you would not have to declare it as global.  Your reply did get through but I only have time to look at this web site once per day at most=there won't be any quick responses from me.

Comment: Checking again to see if that solved the problem or not.  Will check again tomorrow PM

Comment: @CurlyJoe Thanks for checking :D
I was struggling with this for a while now, and just now got it right, uff.
You helped me notice where I was wrong, and what way to go, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simplistic, good-looking and easy to implement solution to this problem I came up with (thanks to CurlyJoe's advice).

*A major pro of this design is that it's easy to adjust it to your frames quantity... you got 5? Just change 1 value and it's good to go! Got 900? Still easy. 6,02*10^23 frames? Still just 1 change ;]*

To adjust to your frame size, just change the list comprehension `range(10)` to whatever quantity you wish, the code will take care of the rest.

```
from tkinter import Tk, PhotoImage, Button, FLAT
root = Tk()
mineImagesList = [PhotoImage(file="Resources/Mine/saperx_mine_%s.png" % (frame)) for frame in range(1, 11)]
button = Button(root, bd=0, relief=FLAT, command= lambda: func(button))


def func (object, frame=0):
    object.configure(image=mineImagesList[frame])
    object.image = mineImagesList[frame]
    print("Object image:", object.image)
    if frame+1 < len(mineImagesList):
        frame += 1
        root.after(34, lambda frame=frame, object=object: func(object=object, frame=frame))

button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```